# Magnitude of magnetic field deciding the type of Zeeman effect

Tags: magnetic-fields, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, spectroscopy

What is magnitude of magnetic field which decides what kind of Zeeman splitting (weak, strong or intermediate) is going to happen?

In textbook it is given that

\begin{align*}
&\mathbf{B}_\text{ext} > \mathbf{B}_\text{int} \implies\text{Strong Field Zeeman Effect}\\
&\mathbf{B}_\text{ext} \approx \mathbf{B}_\text{int} \implies\text{Intermediate Field Zeeman Effect}\\
&\mathbf{B}_\text{ext} < \mathbf{B}_\text{int} \implies\text{Weak Field Zeeman Effect}
\end{align*}

But what is exact magnitude of $\mathbf{B}$ (in Tesla) required to satisfy these conditions?

I need this to solve the following problem.

The spectral line corresponding to an atomic transition from $J=1$ to $J=0$ states split in a magnetic field of $0.1$ Tesla into three components separated by $1.6 \times 10^{-3}$ Angstrom. If the zero field spectral line corresponds to $1849$ Angstrom, what is the g-factor corresponding to $J=1$ state? (You may use $\dfrac{hc}{\mu_0}\approx 2 \times 10^4$ cm)